# What is the difference between regular surfaces and regular parametrized surfaces?

Tags: differential-geometry

Properties of differential geometry to regular parametrized surfaces

[image]

What is the difference between regular surfaces and regular parametrized surfaces?

Answer (score 3):

Regular surface is just some subset $M\subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$ that is smooth 2-dimensional manifold. If there is differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that $f(\mathbb{R}^{2})=M$ then $f$ is [*parametrisation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametrization) of $M$, and $(M,f)$ is regular parametrized surface.